# Table view rounded top corner CAShapeLayer is incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cashapelayer

I used this extension to round two top corner of a table view.

```
self.tableView.roundCorners([.TopLeft, .TopRight], radius: 8)



extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let rect = self.layer.bounds
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.frame = rect
        mask.path = path.CGPath
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.addSublayer(mask)

        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

When I run the app the table view is always clipped off some of the bottom rows, but when I comment out the round corner line, the table worked perfectly fine. Anyone know why this is happen?

*Side notes: if I set the cornerRadius for the table view then it works fine, but it round all four of the corner and I only want it round two top corner.*

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/36092304/77567

Comment: @robmayoff hi Rob, thanks for your link, I tried but did not work for table view, when table scroll down the content is still clipped off. So it's not a duplicate.

Comment: It's the same problem: your mask doesn't match the bounds of your table view. The table view scrolls by changing the origin of its `bounds`, so you need to either reset the mask path every time the table view scrolls, or you need to put the mask on the table view's superview.